# Pipe Operators returning two rows for one comment

Tags: r, nlp, pipe, tidyverse

I am attempting to obtain sentiment scores on comments in a data frame with two columns, Author and Comment. I used the command

```
data %>%
  get_sentences() %>%
  sentiment() -> data_senti
```

to put the result into a variable. The result is more than doubled as each comment is broken down into n amount of rows for n amount of sentences in a comment. How do I keep a comment intact, as in, return only one row for each comment and not break it down to n rows for n sentences in a comment?

=> input example:

[image: Author Comment Bob "I love it. I do not hate it"]

=> preferred output example

[image: Author Comment Sentiment Bob "I love it. I do not hate it" 0.02]

what I actually get:

[image: Author Comment Sentiment Bob "I love it" 1 Bob "I do not hate it" .8]

Full code so far:

```
# load proper libraries; ensure they are already installed
install.packages(c('syuzhet', 'sentimentr', 'tidyverse', 'magrittr', 'dplyr'))
library(syuzhet)
library(sentimentr)
library(tidyverse)

# set working dir
setwd("C:/Users/user3/OneDrive/Desktop/Sentiment_Analysis/Data/Output/Clean Sets")

# import file
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/user3/OneDrive/Desktop/Sentiment_Analysis/Data/Output/Clean Sets/all_comments.csv")

data %>%
  get_sentences() %>%
  sentiment() -> data_senti
```

UPDATE: dput(head(data))

> > structure(list(Primary.Key = c("Google_e1", "Google_e3", "Google_e98"
> > ), Original.Text = c("I feel as though awards are fairly awarded, but the time frame in which awards are given is sometimes  significantly late due at times to admin.  Not providing awards to personnel in a timely fashion can give the  perception that the command does not care about members",
> > "Our all white, all male, all 40 or 50-something leadership is horrible to women and minorities. Every single  person that has had difficulties in the workplace has been a woman, a minority, or both. On the other hand, the  white men (mickey, donald, and others) are allowed to be abusive, dismissive, and unprofessional.  white women (Minnie, and Cardi B and Lovely Jun) are allowed to make a sport out of  gossiping about people and essentially run Mordor like a remake of the Mean Girls movie. I honestly find it hard  to believe that the chain of command has NEVER NOTICED that the people they force out of their jobs are  Latina women, black men, and other minorities, and likewise don't notice that the people they give uncontested  promotions to are white men (Lebron) and white women (Meghan The Horse). Honestly, for an analytical organization,  it's hard to believe that nobody has ever seen it through the eyes of a minority. This is why representation  matters!!!",
> > "I have not observed clear indications of "better treatment" based off of Race, Religion, Sex or sexual prefrence."
> > )), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please show some data

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do not post images of data because we cannot copy/paste those in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO, Père Noël.
Pacakge `{sentimenter}`'s `get_sentences()` breaks the text input into sentences by default, as its name implies. To reconstruct the original text input as the defining key in your final data frame, you need to group and summarize the sentence-based output produced by `sentiment()`.
In this example, I will simply average the sentiment scores, and append sentences by their element_id.

```
library(sentimentr)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Primary.Key   = c("Google_e1", "Google_e3", "Google_e98" ), 
             Original.Text = c("I feel as though awards are fairly awarded, but the time frame in which awards are given is sometimes significantly late due at times to admin. Not providing awards to personnel in a timely fashion can give the perception that the command does not care about members", "Our all white, all male, all 40 or 50-something leadership is horrible to women and minorities. Every single person that has had difficulties in the workplace has been a woman, a minority, or both. On the other hand, the white men (mickey, donald, and others) are allowed to be abusive, dismissive, and unprofessional. white women (Minnie, and Cardi B and Lovely Jun) are allowed to make a sport out of gossiping about people and essentially run Mordor like a remake of the Mean Girls movie. I honestly find it hard to believe that the chain of command has NEVER NOTICED that the people they force out of their jobs are Latina women, black men, and other minorities, and likewise don't notice that the people they give uncontested promotions to are white men (Lebron) and white women (Meghan The Horse). Honestly, for an analytical organization, it's hard to believe that nobody has ever seen it through the eyes of a minority. This is why representation matters!!!", "I have not observed clear indications of 'better treatment' based off of Race, Religion, Sex or sexual prefrence." ))


df %>% 
  get_sentences() %>% 
  sentiment() %>% 
  group_by(Primary.Key, element_id) %>% 
  summarise(comment = paste(Original.Text, collapse = " "), 
            sentiment = mean(sentiment)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Primary.Key element_id comment                                                sentiment
  <chr>            <int> <chr>                                                      <dbl>
1 Google_e1            1 I feel as though awards are fairly awarded, but the t~   -0.0410
2 Google_e3            2 Our all white, all male, all 40 or 50-something leade~   -0.0735
3 Google_e98           3 I have not observed clear indications of 'better trea~   -0.0943
```

Comment: I have implemented the code, but I am only getting one row back. The data have 6000+ rows. This is what I have implemented: ``` data %>%
  get_sentences("Original Text") %>%
  sentiment() %>%
  group_by("Primary Key", "element_id") %>% 
  summarise(comment = paste(Original.Text, collapse = " "),
            sentiment = mean(sentiment)) %>% 
  ungroup() ```

Comment: Why are you placing "Original Text" in double quotes inside `get_sentences()`? 
Could you share with us at least a subset of your object called `data`?

Comment: "Original Text" is the column with the comments. I am not sure how to paste the data in the right format into here. Can I perhaps start a chat with you?

Comment: Try  dput(head(data)) -where `data` is your object, and paste the results into the question.

Comment: Helo Père, I updated the answer with your example.

Comment: Perfect! It worked!! I notice you removed the column's name from "get_sentences()"; I think that's what what preventing me from getting the preferred results!!

Comment: Indeed, that might have been the problem.
Now, be careful, as both {syuzhet} and {sentimentr} have similar but different `get_sentences()` implementations. 
In this case I am using `sentimentr::get_sentences()`,
which wraps around {textshape}'s `split_sentences()` by accepting either character vectors, or data frames. In the second case, `textshape::split_sentences()` is forced to try to guess which of the data frame variable has the text, as sentimentr::get_sentences() does not a good job passing the correct variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `get_sentences` function is designed to parse into rows.  For many analyses, that would make sense.  Anyway, here's how I addressed the issue:

```
data<-as.data.frame(c("I love it. I do not hate it"))
data$who<-"Bob"  # since you didn't share data i added this
colnames(data)[1]<-"mysent"

data %>%
  get_sentences() %>%
  sentiment() -> data_senti

data_senti  # examine
```

So, if you'd like to regroup into one person, you can do this:

```
library(tidyr)
data_senti %>% group_by(who) %>% 
  summarise(combo_1 = paste(mysent, collapse = " "))->k
```

Comment: When I implement this, it is returning only the Author and the sentiment column. How can I also include the comment?